# How to pass URL params to render function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have React Router that looks like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" render={() => <DashboardView {...dashboardViewProps} />} />
  <Route path="/blocks" render={() => <BlocksView {...blocksViewProps} />} />
  <Route path="/chaincodes" render={() => <ChaincodeView {...chaincodeViewProps} />} />
  <Route path="/channels" render={() => <ChannelsView {...channelsViewProps} />} />
  <Route path="/network" render={() => <NetworkView  {...networkViewProps} />} />
</Switch>
```

I want to add new route like this:

```
<Route path="/transactions/:txId" render={() => <TransactionsView {...transactionsViewProps} />} />
```

How could I pass the txId to the TransactionView constructor which now looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

txId is available to the Router component though the router props, and when you render a component through `render props`, you need to pass the router props to the component

```
<Route path="/transactions/:txId" render={(routerProps) => <TransactionsView {...transactionsViewProps} {...routerProps}/>} />
```

and then in the component you can get it like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.txId = props.match.params.txId
}
```